# Get value of twodimensinal dynamic array from storred pointer adress

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im trying to get all values of a dynamic array initialised like this:

```
      string** structure= new string*[nombre_attributs]();
            for(int j=0; j<nombre_attributs; j++){
                structure[j]= new string[2]();
            }
```

I can fill it with no problem. I then keep a pointer to this array in an array of pointers called adresses_structures. 
How can I now acces the data in this array?

This attempt:

```
    string  *test = adresses_structures[i];
    cout << "Value:" << *(test+0)<<endl;
    cout << "Value:" << *(test+1)<<endl;
    cout << "Value:" << *(test+2)<<endl;
```

doesn't work for all values from the second line in the array. 
I have tried tons of combinations as

```
    for(int k=0; k<2;k++){
            for(int j=0;j<2;j++){
      cout << "Truc:" << *(test + k*2 + j)<<endl;

           }
    }
```

but nothing seem to be able to get the values on the second line. 
Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I just answered this but then noticed the difference in names.  You have `structure` which holds your array, and I had assumed this is the same as `adresses_structures`.  Is that right?

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector<std::vector<std::string>>`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie got this as an assigment and I'm strictly forbidden to use them. I would never do it without them. But I'm sure there is a way

Comment: @paddy structures is an array containing arrays[2] and adresses_structures containes the pointer to the differents structures.

Comment: So you mean `adresses_structures` is of type `string***`?

Comment: I declared it like the following  [code]string *adresses_structures[1];[code] and then insert the adresse like this [code]adresses_structures[0]=*structure;[code]

Comment: In that case you have just stored `structures[0]` into `adresses_structures[0]`.  You may therefore only access `adresses_structures[i]` if `i` is 0.  I think you have confused array and pointer access in an attempt to make broken code compile.

Comment: so you mean I have to declare adresses_structures with ***   ? like ***adresses_structures

Comment: No.  There's no point declaring it as an array that holds one element.  Just do: `string ** adresses_structures = structures;`  You're just copying the pointer, right?

Comment: I don't really get what you are trying to say... adresses_structures is supposed to hold several pointers pointing each one to another structure in white i try to access data...

Comment: In that case, yes.  It needs to be `string***` because you have another level of indirection.  It's a three-dimensional array.

Answer (score -1):

I assume, that `string** structure` is the same as `adresses_structures` here.

When You are doing `*(test+1)` You move by one byte from `test` address. You should move by size of string object (check `sizeof(string)`). Like this: `*(test+1*sizeof(string))` or `*(test+2*sizeof(string))`

Comment: The second part. Right, my bad. It is solution if the array were `void*` type

Comment: No, it's not.  You cannot perform pointer arithmetic on `void*`, neither can you dereference.

Comment: my bad, I didn't specify, in adresses_structures I have the pointers to structures.